# Get CodePoint of unicode Character in C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode

I want to get the codepoint for each character in this string "عربى"
so I write this code but it always output 63 which is the codepoint of the question mark character "?"

```
TCHAR   myString[50] = _T("عربى");
int stringLength=_tcslen(_T(myString));

for(int i=0;i<stringLength;i++)
{
   unsigned int number =myString[i];
   cout<<number<<endl;
}
```

any suggestions ? :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996667/c-utf-8-lightweight-permissive-code

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to use a library

Comment: In that case, you can use this: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code, and by removing the `_T(myString)` cast into simply `myString`, it worked. Here is the full program.

```
#include <afxwin.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    TCHAR   myString[50] = _T("عربى");
    int stringLength = _tcslen(myString); // <----- edit here

    for(int i=0;i<stringLength;i++)
    {
       unsigned int number =myString[i];
       cout<<number<<endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1593
1585
1576
1609
```

Comment: This probably doesn't work with code points that consist of more than 2 code units in utf-8. Then again, OP might not need those scripts.

Comment: @Nasser : Thank you so much for your help :)
user2079303 : Could you plz give an example as I don't understand what you mean and  thank you for ur great help :)

Comment: @RehabReda: It is my understanding that `TCHAR` is 16 bits wide (if unicode is enabled). A 32 bit wide code point will be represented by 2 code units in UTF-16. This code still iterates the string by (16 bits wide) code unit rather than code point. For example this character:  (http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?page=10&subpage=3&glyph=10302), the code would print 55296 57090 instead of 66306. (at least I think so, the code doesn't compile in my compiler). I've added an answer that works with all current unicode but requires c++11.

Answer (score 3):

Here's code that uses only the standard library and iterates the string by 32-bit wide code units. In the latest UTF-32 this matches up with code points.

```
using namespace std;
const auto str = u8"عربى";
wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> cv;
auto str32 = cv.from_bytes(str);
for(auto c : str32)
    cout << uint_least32_t(c) << '\n';
```

If your standard library hasn't implemented these features yet, you should probably use an external library.